# How to make textarea expand after filling its height?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `textarea` with a specific minimum height and based on [this article](https://alistapart.com/article/expanding-text-areas-made-elegant) I made it expandable. The problem is that it expands before it fills its minimum height,so I want it first to fill its given height and then expand.

here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1bxu2hr6/2/)

And here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="expand js-expand">
  <pre><span></span><br></pre>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.expand {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width:83%; 
  min-height: calc(5rem - 0.5rem - 0.5rem); 
  position: relative; 
  background-color:  #ffffff; 
}

.expand textarea,
.expand pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: left;  
  width: calc(100% - 0.5rem - 1rem);
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem 0.5rem 0.5rem;
    
}

.expand textarea {
    resize: none;
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    overflow: visible;
  
}
```

JS:

```
expandtextarea(document.querySelector('.js-expand'));

function expandtextarea(container) {
    var tarea = container.querySelector('textarea');
    var mirror = container.querySelector('span');
    tarea.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
        mirror.textContent = tarea.value;
    });
}
```

I tried to set a minimum height for `textarea` and `pre` elements to be the same as the container `div` but it did not change a thing.

I'll be glad for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The observed issue that the textarea expand ahead of the input is because you have not reset the margin of the `<pre>` element, which is the actual element that dictates the height of the parent element.

This means that the space occupied by `<pre>` will always be it's height + (non-zero) margin, which causes that extra space and giving the illusion that you have an extra line at the end of the textarea.

If you simply reset it to `margin: 0`, you will see that your `<textarea>` will now have the same computed outer height as the `<pre>` element:

```js
expandtextarea(document.querySelector('.js-expand'));


function expandtextarea(container) {
 var tarea = container.querySelector('textarea');
 var mirror = container.querySelector('span');
 tarea.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  mirror.textContent = tarea.value;
 });
}
```

```css
.expand {
 max-height: 200px;
 overflow: hidden;
  width:83%; 
  min-height: calc(5rem - 0.5rem - 0.5rem); 
  position: relative; 
  background-color: #eee; 
}

.expand textarea,
.expand pre {
 white-space: pre-wrap;
 word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: left;  
  width: calc(100% - 0.5rem - 1rem);
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem 0.5rem 0.5rem;
  
  /* Reset margin */
  margin: 0;
}

.expand textarea {
 resize: none;
 border: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0; left: 0;
 overflow: visible;
  
  /* Irrelevant style, added for visibility only */
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="expand js-expand">
  <pre><span></span><br></pre>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you it worked perfect, I did not expect it to be that simple

Answer (score 2):

Terry already gave a correct answer. This is just another solution to get a simple auto-expanding textarea, without JavaScript, using `contenteditable`:

```js
// Just some JS to get the value...
document.getElementsByTagName( 'button' )[ 0 ].addEventListener( 'click', () => {
  const tarea = document.querySelector( '.textarea' );
  const value = tarea.innerText;
  
  console.log( value );
} );
```

```css
.textarea {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  min-height: 4rem;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable class="textarea" aria-role="textbox"></div>
<button>Get value</button>
```

Comment: Thanks your answer is correct too but I'm required to use the technique which mentioned in the article

Comment: No worries. Just wanted to give another solution.